# Why CALayer, [CATransaction commit], not react instantly in scrollViewDidScroll:

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

Inserted a `CALayer`, and then `[CATransaction commit]` in `scrollViewDidScroll:`

why it not reacts instantly  in `scrollViewDidScroll:`?

to quick drag issues, there is a a flash blank.

[image: q]

slow handling is OK

[image: img normal]

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.backLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    self.backLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, KScreenWidth, 0);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: self.backLayer];
    self.backLayer.backgroundColor = navigationBarBuleColor.CGColor;
    self.backLayer.actions = @{@"position":[NSNull null]};
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (y>0) {
        self.backLayer.opacity = 0;
    }
    else{

        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
        CGRect frame = self.backLayer.frame;
        frame.size.height = (fabs(y));
        self.backLayer.frame = frame;
        self.backLayer.opacity = 1;
        [CATransaction commit];
    }
}
```

I have checked [Update CALayer sublayers immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380649/update-calayer-sublayers-immediately).

And I use UIView, it is OK.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.assistView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, KScreenWidth, 0)];
    self.assistView.backgroundColor = navigationBarBuleColor;
    [self.view addSubview:self.assistView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (y>0) {
        self.assistView.alpha = 0;
    } else{
        CGRect frame = self.assistView.frame;
        frame.size.height = (fabs(y));
        self.assistView.frame = frame;
        self.assistView.alpha = 1;
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

what it the method of CALayer , equal to `setNeedsLayout`?

More info: I try to solve the problem with layer [How to set UITableView empty space's backgroundColor different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114423/how-to-set-uitableview-empty-spaces-backgroundcolor-different)